# Memory leak when resizing images using CoreGraphics on background thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, core-graphics

I'm building an app that uploads resized versions of many images to the server, and I seem to have a memory leak that I can't track down.  Here's my method that creates the multi-part request (using Restkit 0.2):

```
[self.objectManager
     multipartFormRequestWithObject:nil
     method:RKRequestMethodPUT
     path:pathString
     parameters:@{@"photo": photoParamater}
     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
       @autoreleasepool {
         if (uploadImage) {
           NSData *imageData =
           [photo scaledImageDataWithSmallerDimension:IMAGE_UPLOAD_SMALLER_DIMENSION
                                   compressionQuality:IMAGE_UPLOAD_JPEG_QUALITY];
           imageDataBytes += imageData.length;
           [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                                       name:photo.file_key.absoluteString
                                   fileName:photo.filename
                                   mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
         }
       }
     }];
```

This is part of a method that is called from the main() function of a NSOperation on a background queue.

Here's are the photo methods that get me the actual photo data.  The meat of it is in //3

```
//1
- (NSData *)scaledImageDataWithSmallerDimension:(CGFloat)length compressionQuality:(float)quality
{
    CGSize newSize = [self scaledSizeWithSmallerDimension:length];
    return [self imageDataResizedToFitSize:newSize compressionQuality:quality];
}

//2
- (NSData *)imageDataResizedToFitSize:(CGSize)size compressionQuality:(float)quality
{
    return [self thumbnailDataForAsset:self.asset maxPixelSize:MAX(size.height, size.width) compressionQuality:quality];
}

//3
- (NSData *)thumbnailDataForAsset:(ALAsset *)asset
                     maxPixelSize:(NSUInteger)size
               compressionQuality:(float)quality {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSParameterAssert(asset != nil);
    NSParameterAssert(size > 0);

    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

    CGDataProviderDirectCallbacks callbacks = {
      .version = 0,
      .getBytePointer = NULL,
      .releaseBytePointer = NULL,
      .getBytesAtPosition = getAssetBytesCallback,
      .releaseInfo = releaseAssetCallback,
    };

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateDirect((void *)CFBridgingRetain(rep),
                                                            [rep size],
                                                            &callbacks);
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider(provider, NULL);

    NSDictionary *imageOptions =
    @{
      (NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways : @YES,
      (NSString *)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:size],
      (NSString *)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform : @YES,
      };
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source,
                                                              0,
                                                              (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) imageOptions);
    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(provider);

    if (!imageRef) {
      return nil;
    }


    NSMutableData *outputData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    CGImageDestinationRef destRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef) outputData,
                                                                     kUTTypeJPEG,
                                                                     1,
                                                                     NULL);
    NSDictionary *imageAddOptions =
    @{
      (NSString *)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:quality],
      };
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destRef,
                               imageRef,
                               (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) imageAddOptions);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destRef);
    CFRelease(imageRef);
    CFRelease(destRef);

    return outputData;
  }
}

// Helper methods for thumbnailDataForAsset:maxPixelSize:
static size_t getAssetBytesCallback(void *info, void *buffer, off_t position, size_t count) {
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = (__bridge id)info;

    NSError *error = nil;
    size_t countRead = [rep getBytes:(uint8_t *)buffer fromOffset:position length:count error:&error];

    if (countRead == 0 && error) {
        // We have no way of passing this info back to the caller, so we log it, at least.
        NSLog(@"thumbnailForAsset:maxPixelSize: got an error reading an asset: %@", error);
    }

    return countRead;
}

static void releaseAssetCallback(void *info) {
    // The info here is an ALAssetRepresentation which we CFRetain in thumbnailDataForAsset:maxPixelSize:.
    // This release balances that retain.
    CFRelease(info);
}
```

Note that I started using these after I experienced a similar memory leak using UIImageJPEGRepresentation() on a method that turned the CGImageRef into a UIImageinstead.

I'm pretty sure that there's a memory leak because the app eventually terminates due to a memory error.  When I run instruments on it, there are tons of living malloc 464/592/398 KB allocations, which instruments gives this stack for:

```
   0 libsystem_malloc.dylib malloc_zone_realloc
   1 libsystem_malloc.dylib realloc
   2 Foundation _NSMutableDataGrowBytes
   3 Foundation -[NSConcreteMutableData appendBytes:length:]
   4 ImageIO CGImageWriteSessionPutBytes
   5 ImageIO emptyOutputBuffer
   6 ImageIO encode_mcu_huff
   7 ImageIO compress_data
   8 ImageIO process_data_simple_main
   9 ImageIO _cg_jpeg_write_scanlines
  10 ImageIO writeOne
  11 ImageIO _CGImagePluginWriteJPEG
  12 ImageIO CGImageDestinationFinalize
  13 MyApp -[MyPhoto thumbnailDataForAsset:maxPixelSize:compressionQuality:] 
  14 MyApp -[MyPhoto imageDataResizedToFitSize:compressionQuality:] 
  15 MyApp -[MyPhoto scaledImageDataWithSmallerDimension:compressionQuality:]
```

Is this a bug in CGImageDestinationFinalize or am I responsible for freeing something I'm not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My initial reaction is that you're creating a lot of images and holding them in memory for transmission (the `appendPartData` part)  Is it possible that you're just running out of memory without an actual leak?  Can you write the individual images to temporary files and then use RestKit to upload those?

Comment: Thanks David, but the multipart form request is only posting a single image at a time.  There are 2 threads uploading, so there should only be 2 images in memory at any given time.  On my 5S it gets through hundreds of images successfully before running out of memory.  I also have a second function that does almost exactly the same thing but posts a batch of 100 thumbnails at the same and does _not_ seem to trigger this leak, which makes it all the more baffling to me.

Comment: I'm trying to do something on OSX that is almost identical and observing the same problem. Did you figure out a workaround or resolve this in some other way?

Comment: Sorry, not that I recall, I stopped working on the app that uploaded all the thumbnails shortly after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked over your code pretty carefully and the memory management appears sound. You have the key bits enclosed in @autoreleasepool blocks, so any autorleased objects should be cleaned up. Your handling of CF objects also looks correct. (Admittedly memory bugs can be hard to spot...)

If you get a similar sort of leak when using the system method UIImageJPEGRepresentation, it starts to smell more and more like a system bug. Have you tested it against different OS versions (on device). It might be that this leak is new to iOS 7, and does not show up in older iOS versions. If so, it's important to make Apple aware of the bug quickly so they actually fix it in 7, rather than ignoring it until iOS 8 is released.

And have you tested it on device as well as on the sim? I have, more than once in the past, spent a lot of time trying to track down apparent memory leaks when running my code on the sim, only to conclude that the bug was actually in the simulator implementation of system libraries, and the exact same code did not leak when run on a device.

I would suggest submitting 2 bugs to Apple's bug reporter system: The leak in your `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` approach, as well as the leak in the `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex` approach. Provide minimal test applications in both cases, or Apple's wonderful (read clueless) bug screeners will kick it back to you immediately.

Once the front-line bug screeners run out of stupid reasons to kick it back to you, they should submit it to the real engineers, who can determine if it really is a framework bug or not. (Can you tell I have a low opinion of the first-level bug screeners at Apple?)

Comment: Thanks Duncan, I've come to the same conclusion.  I'm definitely running on device (iPhone 5S).  After continuing to bang my head against the wall, I tried replacing just the call to CGImageDestinationFinalize(destRef); with a for loop that puts 400K of 0's in the mutabledata object instead, and the memory leak vanished, which makes me pretty confident I'm not hanging on to it in the wrong way.  I'll try making a repro app and submitting to Apple as you suggest.  Thanks for taking the time to look over my memory management in detail!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use so much complex things when the framework already provides one. The ImageIO frameworks has some functions which lets you create the thumbnails from the source image.

```
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url);
NSDictionary *options = (CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary 
dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1024
forKey:(id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize];

CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(src,0,options);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnail];
CGImageRelease(thumbnail);
CGImageSourceRelease(src);
```

Comment: Hello insane-36, I'm looking for an NSData object as the output, not a UIImage.  As I mentioned in the post, I tried using a function that resizes the image, then using UIImageJPEGRepresentation to turn it into NSData, but I had the same leak.  I tried substituting my image resize code for what you posted, since it does look simpler, but I had to modify it a bit (CGImageSourceCreateWithURL takes an options dict, url I set from asset.defaultRepresentation.url) and get an error: <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -11.

Comment: Well, the function parameter with the CGImageSourceCreateWithURL takes are the source image url and the options. Try with the url only for the first time without any of the options. However, the options also look simpler as described here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Image_Source_Option_Dictionary_Keys.

Comment: I tried both variants in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hbridge/42de971eba5bbc7f9bf4).  Both return error -11.  Are you sure ALAssetRepresentation URLs work for CGCreateWithURL?  If not the provider stuff above seems like the right way to read the assets.

Comment: BTW: this is the blog post where I got the approach I'm using: http://www.mindsea.com/2012/12/downscaling-huge-alassets-without-fear-of-sigkill/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and after trying various methods and solutions, I tried also using autoreleasepool and it did't help... and after a while I came across the following insights:

When dealing with images using UIImage and CGImage system methods, it consumes a significant amount of memory. For instance, a simple image with dimensions around 4000px x 3000px can take up approximately 45MB of memory. If your app needs to handle multiple images or if you're working with a share extension, it's possible for your app to exhaust all available memory and crash. Share extensions have a limited memory allocation of only 120MB, other extension even have even less memory, so working with larger images (above 7000px in height/width) can easily lead to app crashes. This issue has even affected some of the most popular apps on iOS.

So, there is no straightforward solution other than avoiding the handling of large image files or using third-party tools.

One such open-source library that addresses this problem, (and which I used to solve this problem) is SDWebImage, available at https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage. After importing this library into your project, you can use it to handle images without worrying about memory leaks or crashes.

Here's an example of how you can use SDWebImage in your project to resize or compress image:

```
func resizeImage(atPath imagePath: URL) -> UIImage? {
    guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath.path) else { return nil }
    
    guard let thumbnailData = SDImageIOCoder.shared.encodedData(with: image, format: .undefined, options: [.encodeMaxPixelSize: CGSize(width: 1920, height: 1920), .encodeCompressionQuality: 0.7]) else { return nil }
    
    return SDImageIOCoder.shared.decodedImage(with: thumbnailData)
}
```

Comment: Please don't add the [same answer to multiple questions](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates, once you earn enough reputation. If it is not a duplicate, [edit] the answer and tailor the post to the question.